# Async Task outputting in chinese characters instead of readable text

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I am attempting to search files for specific text using an async Task. The output I receive is in chinese characters instead of what is actually in the text file I am parsing. Here is the code:

```
    public async void ProcessRead(string fileLocation)
    {
        string filePath = fileLocation;

        if (File.Exists(filePath) == false)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("file not found: " + filePath);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                string text = await ReadTextAsync(filePath);
                Debug.WriteLine(text);
                if (text.Contains(inputContentPattern))
                {
                    addToDataGrid(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath, "");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        findButton.Enabled = true;
        cancelFindButton.Enabled = false;
    }

    private async Task<string> ReadTextAsync(string filePath)
    {
        using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
            bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
            int numRead;
            while ((numRead = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                string text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
                sb.Append(text);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is/was the encoding to write the file?

Comment: Don't confuse the question by including the fact that it's async.  That's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the file using Unicode encoding (in an incorrect way). Find out what encoding the file actually has and use that encoding. Simply use `File.ReadAllText` and delete `ReadTextAsync`.

Async IO brings you zero performance benefits here so just don't do it. If this is a UI app use `await Task.Run(() => File.ReadAllText(...))`.

Comment: Not sure, but I would at least go for `ReadLines` as this returns `IEnumerable<string>`, which gives at least the chance to create a non-blocking/parallel producer-consumer chain ...

Comment: ReadLines is based on sync IO. You'll block at least one thread which will be at least as bad as using ReadAllText. File IO performance is either limited by disk or by CPU processing speeds. Whether it is sync or async does not matter for throughput (except under unusual circumstances).

Comment: @usr Could you expand a bit on *Async IO brings you zero performance benefits here so just don't do it*. It is not obvious what you're referring.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel what perf benefits do you have in mind? Async IO uses more CPU. And if this file IO uses the disk then the physical operation will not be any faster. You see: More CPU usage, equal disk usage.; Async IO is about saving memory and reducing context switches. This is not a concern here.

Comment: Why would async IO uses more cpu? AFAICT IO doesn't even needs the cpu to work. It is purely hardware work, we just need threads and cpu to initiate that operation. Async IO just don't block any thread which is definitely a desirable thing. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it is true that the CPU is only being used to setup/initiate the hardware IO. But that setup is more expensive. For example there are now two transitions to the kernel instead of one. One for the initiation, one for receiving the completion notification. Also more allocations and synchronized memory access inside the Task class. Benchmark it, you'll see for yourself. More CPU.

Comment: Since the degree of parallelism that you use to access a disk is low memory and thread savings are negligible. Even if we were assuming that there are CPU savings - they would be tiny. Total misinvestment of developer time.

Comment: @usr: I agree that file access is something that can easily be synchronous without harming the app - assuming that: the file access is local, the app is a desktop app, etc. But note that the synchronous file APIs are using *asynchronous* I/O operations at the kernel level, so there's no inherent performance benefit to blocking I/O at all.

Comment: @StephenCleary I'm surprised to hear this from someone as experienced as you. I can only encourage you to run a benchmark yourself. These statements of mine are not hypothetical.; Async IO *does* block sometimes as well: When the CLR calls GetQueuedCompletionStatus! We still have blocking but now with two kernel transitions instead of one. Also, I have explained the .NET level overheads in a previous comment.; Another evidence: Why does the Socket class support awkward event based IO? In order to reduce the .NET level overhead. This shows that the overhead is significant.

Comment: Async IO can *save* CPU but only under high load when it reduces context switches and kernel transitions. Under low load, which most servers operate under in order to have capacity margin, it hurts CPU usage. Async IO is mainly useful to save memory and to make UI programming easier since C# 5.

Comment: there's no deferred exexution involved on `ReadLines`?! at least you could start processing as soon as lines come in and not wait on all lines to be read ... that was my intention...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair understood, and this is true and a valid technique. I'm just cautioning because most of the time this is a total waste of dev time. If you are worried about IO efficiency: The kernel already prefetches the next bytes of the file so that there is natural overlap built-in. This reduces the need for manual pipeline building.

Comment: yes, but changing one call is a less bigger deal than implementing async imho. and you never know how big the file is - so a potential memory saver as well...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair agreed.